# HTML/JS/JSON- Take user input and add it to JSON payload as an JSON object

Tags: javascript, html, json

So I have a HTML page that asks for First name and Last name for new customers (to be added into the database).

```
<tr><td>
  <label for="firstName">First Name: </label></td><td>
  <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" v-model="firstName"></td> </tr>
<tr><td>
 <label for="lastName">Last Name: </label></td><td>
  <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" v-model="lastName"></td> </tr>
<tr><td>
```

Now, when user submits this information, I can use JavaScript to store user input into a variable. I know this is done by

```
Document.getElementById("firstName")
Document.getElementById("lastName")
```

I have a URL that contains JSON objects of every registered customer

```
localhost:8080/customer/all
```

My question is- How do I add the new customer's information so it becomes a JSON object as well?

Comment: What is your server? And it is hard to answer without server code.

Answer (score 0):

SInce you know how to assign to variable its simple. just assign that varialbe as value to object key

```
var value = Document.getElementById("firstName")
var obj = {
 key : value
}
```

Hoping this is what you mean by the question

Answer (score 0):

```js
function calc(){
  var data = {
  firstname : document.getElementById("firstName").value,
  lastname : document.getElementById("lastName").value
  }

  console.log(data);


}
```

```html
<tr><td>
  <label for="firstName">First Name: </label></td><td>
  <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" v-model="firstName"></td> </tr>
<tr><td>
 <label for="lastName">Last Name: </label></td><td>
  <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" v-model="lastName"></td> </tr>
<tr><td>

<input type="button" onClick="calc()" value="Submit">
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```js
function createObj() {
  var firstname = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
  var lastname = document.getElementById("lastName").value;
  
  var customerInfo = {
    "firstname" : firstname,
    "lastname" : lastname
  }
  
  console.log(customerInfo);
}
```

```html
<tr><td>
  <label for="firstName">First Name: </label></td><td>
  <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" v-model="firstName"></td> </tr>
<tr><td>
 <label for="lastName">Last Name: </label></td><td>
  <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" v-model="lastName"></td> </tr>
<tr><td>
<input type="submit" onClick="createObj()" value="Submit">
```